# Fullcalendar not showing any event (backend Codeigniter)

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, fullcalendar

This has me driving nuts since i cant seem to find anything thats wrong with my code or json. I already spent many hours trying to solve it and reading allot of answers on StackOverflow aswell.

I have the following pieces of code:

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        editable: true,

        events: "/action/json/calender",
        allDayDefault: false,
        eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
            alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
                '(should probably update your database)');
        },

        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) $('#loading').show();
            else $('#loading').hide();
        }

    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function calender()
{
    $this->load->model('json_model');
    $data['json'] = $this->json_model->getCalender();
    $this->load->view('json/calender', $data);
}
```

**Model**

```
function getCalender()
{
    $sql = "SELECT id, title, start, end, user_id FROM gc_calender";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $result;
}
```

**View**

```
<?php
$jsonevents = array();

foreach($json->result() as $entry)
{
$jsonevents[] = array(
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => $entry->title,
    'start' => $entry->start,
    'end' => $entry->end,
    'allDay' => ''
);

}

 echo json_encode($jsonevents);
```

**JSON example**

```
[{"id":1,"title":"title 1","start":"2013-09-08 00:00:00","end":"2013-09-08 10:00:00","allDay":""},{"id":1,"title":"title 2","start":"2013-09-17 00:00:00","end":"2013-09-17 10:00:00","allDay":""}]
```

What i've already tried:

- Hardcode it in Javascript itself
- PHP header so it's being outputted as json
- Older version of fullcalender

Here's the fun part.. the demo that comes with the package works for me. However if i point my jquery code to that specific json url i still get no events. The calender itself gets rendered fine.

Something more that i tried: Using the demo HTML page with the JSON being served by codeigniter and it works.. Im starting to think there's either a conflict with a different script or maybe i need to load my scrips in the header instead of the footer?

Comment: There are no errors in console? I think there is problem in your JavaScript this line `events: "/action/json/calender",` please also note: While using CI please use its active record in your models its much nicer and more secure :), before any `foreach()` make sure you check if there are any data in desired variable (your case: $json) you can make your model return FALSE (or NULL) if there are no results so in your controller you can use simple `if()` statement to check if variable is in desired "format" (array/object).

Comment: There's actually a error in console showing up now, that wasnt before. It started showing up after slightly modyfing the jquery to the one in my question. Ill add it up to the question it self. 

As for active records, im not a big fan and just like the write them myself. The other things i know but its just a test case atm!

Comment: My bad, i misspelled a part of the url thats why it was showing a 404 error. After correction there's no console error and no working calender.

Comment: Are you setting up json headers? in view `$this->output->set_header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');` as first line. Please also open up chromes element inspector hit network tab and see what is going on there. Are ajax responses all good?

Comment: Yes i have tried that before and it makes no difference. Note that the example that does work doesnt use headers.

Comment: If you load your events URL in your browser, do you see the expected events JSON output?

Comment: Yes, the JSON example from my post is the current output as given by the script. When i use that output as the event json url for the json.html demo that comes with the package it does work.

Comment: It might be the fact you are loading the scripts in the footer...

Comment: I thought the same but i havn't tried it and this is why: It does change the div to a calender layout it just doesnt fills the calender with events. If there was a problem it shouldnt change the div to a calender in the first place right?

Comment: To be sure i have tested to see if it makes a difference or not and the answer is no. Header or at the end of the body there is no difference. I even moved the header info to the bottom in the working example and that still works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i could have saved myself 2 days if i checked the header aswell... Our designer added the following to the css:

```
div {
position:relative;
overflow:hidden
}
```

After removing this, it just works fine. Cant believe it was this simple.

Comment: I knew there is some html/css bug.

Answer (score 1):

IT WORKS FOR ME, TRY IT!

**Controller**

```
public function show_calendar() 
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY start ASC");

    $jsonevents = array();

    foreach($query->result() as $entry)
    {
        $jsonevents[] = array(
            'id' => $entry->id,
            'title' => $entry->title,
            'start' => $entry->start,
            'end' => $entry->end,
            'url' => $entry->url,
            'allDay' => $entry->allDay
        );
    }

    $data['json'] = json_encode($jsonevents);

    $this->load->view('calendar',$data); 
}
```

**View**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events:<?php echo $json ?>,

        header: 
        {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek'
        }          
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your event reference from "events" to "eventSources":

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

  editable: true,
  eventSources: [ { url: '/action/json/calender' } ],
  allDayDefault: false,
  eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
      alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
          '(should probably update your database)');
  },
  loading: function(bool) {
    if (bool) $('#loading').show();
      else $('#loading').hide();
  }

});
```

Comment: Unfortunately no change.. the demo that comes with the download however does work if use eventSources instead of event. I tried removing scripts one at the time to see if it was interfering with anything but no luck on that aswell.

Comment: Do you happen to have this available on a public URL, or is this all being developed locally?

Comment: It's on a webserver but it's being used in the backend part of the website. I could make a copy with just basicly the calender ill reply once its done.